# Is it possible to install servermanagercmd in Server 2008 R2 Core Install?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I understand ocsetup should be used in this situation, however I am attempting to install a piece of software that *should* run in core R2 with .net installed. There are no instructions on doing this from the vendor.

The setup.exe uses servermanagercmd to query if prereqs are installed [they are] but it blows up because it can't use that cmd. Is there anyway I can just install that file to bypass this issue? If so, where can i get it?

Answer (score 2):

From everything I've read, no.

I would talk with the vendor about getting a patch. It looks like servermanagercmd is deprecated anyway if this [blog entry](http://www.realtime-windowsserver.com/os_features_troubleshooting/2009/06/servermanagercmdexe_is_depreca.htm) is to be believed.